# adding react-big-calendar will cause Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'matches' of null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, react-on-rails

### reproducing repo

https://github.com/github0013/ror_rbc/commit/246f6e1839cdd6aababeeacb9301a80b040e453d

```rb
# git clone, then
bundle && npm install 
foreman start -f Procfile.dev # should start the server at http://localhost:3000/hello_world
```

#### problem

I am using
https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails
to build a web app, but if I try to `import BigCalendar from 'react-big-calendar'` in a jsx file, it gives the error in the title.

#### things I checked

https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar
this library uses
https://github.com/react-bootstrap/dom-helpers
and
https://github.com/react-bootstrap/dom-helpers/blob/master/src/query/matches.js#L7
this line `document.body` is null as far as I checked.

#### why document is null?

I am quite new to reactjs, webpack and etc, so I am sure I am missing some basic knowledges, but if anyone can point out why document object is missing, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason.

https://github.com/github0013/ror_rbc/commit/3ef648d1ea3d647557b335ca6c5bdf7bd64c88b4

The javascript files were linked inside `HEAD` tag, that is before `BODY` tag.  So when it was to load since `BODY` tag was not yet appeared, it was missing `document.body`.

Moving `javascript_include_tag` at the bottom of `BODY` tag fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solution in an my app and then got another error. More than one Polly-fill loading. React On Rails forum said JavaScript file are normally loaded in the HEAD tag.

Comment: did you clone my repo master and got that error? or your own app?

Comment: I tried moving the tag in my app. The errer msg: Uncaught Error: only one instance of babel-polyfill is allowed. The error is keeping my bootstrap JS from running on my other pages in the app.

Comment: did you move the `javascript_include_tag` line only?  either way, you are talking about "bootstrap" library.  I am talking about "BigCalendar" in this question.

this may help?
https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/issues/1316